# How can I trigger a delete action on a table with an if-statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, plsql, triggers

I'm developing this trigger for a personal project and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The trigger compiles fine and, testing what the trigger is supposed to do, it works ... but the condition isn't working. The trigger just does nothing

Here's my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER z_delete
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OR INSERT OF status ON TABLE_1
FOR EACH ROW


BEGIN
IF (:new.condition_1 = 'I' or :new.condition_2 ='Z')
  THEN

  DELETE TABLE_2 WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE TABLE_1.Value_1 = TABLE_2.Value_2 AND TABLE_1.condition_1='I');


  DELETE interference_results WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE TABLE_1.Value_1 = TABLE_2.Value_3 AND TABLE_1.condition_1 = 'I');

END IF;

END z_delete;
```

Anyone has any idea whats going on??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would expect a reference to `:NEW` or `:OLD` somewhere  in a trigger.

Comment: Hi @Luisao and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please explain this "and, testing what the trigger is supposed to do, it works " in combination with this: "The trigger just does nothing". Thanks!

Comment: I’m surprised it compiles, because the second delete statement refers to a `table_2` that isn’t in any `from` or `join` clause, and I’m surprised it doesn’t give a ‘table is mutating’ error at runtime when it queries the same table the trigger is based on. How similar is this to your actual code?

Comment: I agree with @WilliamRobertson. And also, try to be active when you ask a question, there are two answers already and few comments and no answer or reaction from the OP...

Answer (score 0):

Well your question is : "Anyone has any idea whats going on??". So I i wll try to answer that question.

1. In the begining of your code for the trigger you have some code you do not need:

   ```
   BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OR INSERT OF status ON TABLE_1
   ```

   This will be enough:

   ```
   BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE OF status ON TABLE_1
   ```
2. Then in your trigger the first `DELETE` command is ok and the second one is not because the select in the eexist clause is not ok:

   [CHECK THIS EXAMPLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=84b5167db76fe8d377f89fa42e8e52d3)
3. To help you more you need to tell me what is your plan with the second DELETE clause. What is it you want to accomplish ? Is the "interference_results" name of the table or ?

Hope this helps for now...

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance querying the same record you're inserting into TABLE_1? If so, "BEFORE" trigger won't do as the record isn't created yet. Alternatively, use the actual :NEW values in the dependent DML.